# iOS8 keyboard extension and "Background Activity"

Tags: ios8, background-process, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm currently beta testing a keyboard for iOS8, and my users have reported that the keyboard shows up as a "Background Activity" in the battery usage section.

[image]

What could be the cause of it? When the keyboard is not in use, I see 0% cpu usage when running the keyboard on debug. Why is it listed under "Background Activity"?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, iOS 8 extensions are run in a separate process space from that of either the container app or the running app.  Even though the UI of a keyboard extension might be shown by the OS, it is not part of the foreground app.  Thus the run time is reported as, not in either app, but in a background process (background to the app using the keyboard for its textfield/view).

Comment: Hmm, the thing is Swype/Touchpal is reported as not having background process. This is from other users reporting to me about it though.